# xslt count different context with substring

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have a quite complex requirement for XSLT. I need to count the fields with a value that's equal to a substring of its value. I was able to count them but the problem is the context. Please see sample below:

```
         <root>
            <Manager>TC4:12345</Manager>
            <Staff>
                <employee>TC3:22222</employee>
                <employee>TC3:11111</employee>
                <employee>TC3:33333</employee>
            </Staff>
            </root>
         <root>
            <Manager>TC4:67890</Manager>
            <Staff>
                <employee>TC3:44444</employee>
                <employee>TC3:55555</employee>
                <employee>TC3:66666</employee>
            </Staff>
            </root>
```

The output should be something like this:

```
            <Manager>
            <Seniors>
            <Count>3</Count>
            </Seniors>
            </Manager>
            <Manager>
            <Seniors>
            <Count>3</Count>
            </Seniors>
            </Manager>
```

The number of employees with TC3 roles were counted for the 1st manager, then the number of employees with TC3 roles were counted for the 2nd manager as well. I tried doing this but I end up having 6 in the 1st context and 6 in the 2nd context also instead of 3 and 3.

This is my code

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(//root/Staff/employee[substring(.,1,3) = 'TC3'])">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are (assuming all your xml is wrapped in a body tag):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" /> 
    <xsl:template match="body">
        <xsl:for-each select="root">
            <Manager>
            <Seniors>
                <Count><xsl:value-of select="count(./Staff/employee[substring(.,1,3) = 'TC3'])" /></Count>
            </Seniors>
            </Manager>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the source I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <root>
        <Manager>TC4:12345</Manager>
        <Staff>
            <employee>TC3:22222</employee>
            <employee>TC3:11111</employee>
            <employee>TC3:33333</employee>
        </Staff>
        </root>
     <root>
        <Manager>TC4:67890</Manager>
        <Staff>
            <employee>TC3:44444</employee>
            <employee>TC3:55555</employee>
            <employee>TC3:66666</employee>
        </Staff>
   </root>
</body>
```

And here is the output:

```
<Manager>
  <Seniors>
    <Count>3</Count>
  </Seniors>
</Manager><Manager>
  <Seniors>
    <Count>3</Count>
  </Seniors>
</Manager>
```

Comment: It worked binarymax!!! Thanks!!! It's amazing what a simple dot before /staff can do!!!

Answer (score 0):

Write a template `match="root"` and then inside you can use `<xsl:value-of select="count(Staff/employee[substring(.,1,3) = 'TC3'])"/>`.